# disableTooltip input on ngbTooltip is not disabling the tooltip

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have an element with a tooltip which uses ngbTooltip

```
<div ngbTooltip="Tooltip text" disableTooltip="tooltipDisabled" [placement]="['right-top']" container="body">
</div>
```

`tooltipDisabled` is set to true in the typescript file. No matter how I try to modify this I can't get it to be disabled. [Here is the documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/api) which mentions tooltipDisabled. I also can't find any examples/threads about `disableTooltip` anywhere.

[Here is ng-bootstrap/src/tooltip/tooltip.ts source code](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/tooltip/tooltip.ts) if that helps.

Comment: You forgot the `[]`around disableTooltip. So you're passing the literal string "tooltipDisabled", whish is truthy. Which version of ng-bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @JBNizet I initially had the `[]` but it didn't work. I'm using ^4.2.1.

Comment: Can't reproduce, even with that version: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=package.json. You'll have to provide a complete minimal example reproducing the problem (but still not putting the brackets doesn't make much sense).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using an expression in the input parameters, then you need to use the square brackets: `[disableTooltip]="tooltipDisabled"`

Comment: I initially had `[disableTooltip]="tooltipDisabled"` which didn't (and still doesn't) work.

Comment: If I can figure out how to reproduce I'll try posting.

Comment: Do you have set the ChangeDetectionStrategy to OnPush? Maybe you need to trigger the change detection manually, when the `tooltipDisabled` value changes.

Comment: It would be nice if you could reproduce this problem on StackBlitz

Comment: I have made a [StackBlitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-172gqm) which does not reproduce the error. I do not have ChangeDeterctionStrategy set to OnPush. So strange. I'm going to let the issue be for now, thanks for the help.

Comment: The link doesn't have `[disableTooltip]="true"` for some reason. That should be set.

Comment: Which version of angular and bootstrap are you using? On the ng-bootstrap github there is a table, which contains dependencies: https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap#dependencies

Comment: It works now. I had an unrelated Angular build error which I think prevented this from working (I don't understand too well how the Angular build works so I'm not sure how it would have prevented this from working since other things I added were working). I was ignoring the error because I didn't know how to resolve it, but after I did a hacky fix the tooltip is disabled properly. Apologies and thanks for the help.